# I try to send mail using Laravel but Error occurs

Tags: laravel, email

When i try to send mail using Laravel but error occurring
like this

## **"Connection to "process /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i" has been closed unexpectedly."**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ia6V.png)

this is my env

```
`MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=567
MAIL_USERNAME=*******.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="******"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="********.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"`
```

..

Answer (score 1):

This might be the solution.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=**YOUR_GMAIL_EMAIL**
MAIL_PASSWORD=**GENERATED_APP_PASSWORD**
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

On https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords you can create an app password.

Comment: Thankyou for your help it's working properly now

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice if you could test your email locally using mailtrap.io first. If everything is ok on your local, make sure you gmail account could send SMTP emails.
https://help.accredible.com/smtp-setup-in-gmail-inbox

Also change you config to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_USERNAME=<youremail>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<yourpassword>
```